# Is there ant database that will return the reversed position?

Tags: database, software

I recently started an online game as White that began as follows.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. Nf3 f5  2. d3 Nc6  3. e4 e5
```

Here I deliberately decided to lose a tempo with 4. d4 and transpose into a Vienna reversed with the Black pieces.  I knew what I was doing and therefore was able to avail myself of various resources (books/databases) on the Vienna game, but this got me to wondering. Are there any databases against which you can enter a position, and it will also look for the reversed position?

Answer (score 4):

Chessbase opening trees (ctg) detect white/black transpositions.  My database has 59 games starting 1.e3, 9 games where black answered 1...e5, but then 28000+ games for 2.e4.

Answer (score 3):

http://chessok.com/?page_id=352
I've been using this for my correspondence games at chess.com, hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. Although, a simple solution would be to manually input the moves with sides reversed.